# Phalcon - Model ID becomes 0, save() returns true, getMessages() is empty, afterCreate() is executed

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phalcon

I'm trying to save a model instance to the database, a model which I have saved many many times before. But now it seems to have stopped working, through some evil magic.

I am creating an `EmailConfirmation` alongside a `User`. The `User` is successfully saved, but the `EmailConfirmation` is not, despite the framework telling me that it should have been:

Controller code:

```
if($user->save()){
    $confirmation = new EmailConfirmations();
    $confirmation->user = $user;
    var_dump((bool)$confirmation->create()); //true
    var_dump($confirmation->save()); // true
    var_dump($confirmation->refresh());
    /*
    public 'code' => string 'FEfyfzUqxDiuz0z46Ge9pHWywEbOG4vr' (length=32)
    public 'createdAt' => int 1511172203
    public 'modifiedAt' => null
    public 'confirmed' => boolean false
    public 'id' => string '0' (length=1)
    */
    var_dump($confirmation->getMessages()); // array 0 empty
}
```

In the model:

```
public function afterCreate(){
    if(!$this->id){
        throw new \Exception("WTF!"); // is thrown
    }
    // ...
}
```

The models both have an `id` column, defined as:

```
id int(10) unsigned (auto increment)
```

So to me, it seems like the framework goes through all the motions of saving the model, and reports back that it should have been saved, returning `true` on `save()` and `create()` and having no error messages. But obviously, something is wrong here.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Working now after deleting the table and recreating it.. Not a good fix!

Comment: Then maybe you had some metadata caching?

Comment: hi, I encounter this issue, did you solve it?

Comment: As I said in my comment, I solved it by manually dropping the table from the database and recreating it. Not an ideal solution, but I gave up trying to figure out the exact cause.